# Can not install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system

I get the following error while loading Ubuntu. White screen appears with cursor blinking.

```
error screen init failed for driver 0
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu 14.04 installation media seems to not be properly configured.
Burn the **Ubuntu ISO image** to a DVD or create an USB installation media.

To create the media in a running Ubuntu system, use **Ubuntu Disks** tool.
Open **Disks** - select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.
Choose the **ISO file** and the **USB drive** to write it to and **start restoring**.

To create the USB media from a running Windows system,
open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 (quick)  
assign letter=**  
exit
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter
Mount the Ubuntu ISO and copy the content to the USB drive.